# How to place swiper on circle with space between two centered slides?

Tags: javascript, frontend, swiper.js

My problem is to place swiperjs slides on a circle.

Everything I've been able to achieve so far can be seen here: https://codesandbox.io/s/swiper-effect-creative-forked-vvyl73?file=/index.html

The problem is that the company logo should be placed between the two central slides, and the slides should ride around it. Should by smth like this:
[image: what I need]

Maybe someone has dealt with this problem and knows how to solve it?
Or maybe there is an alternative plugin that simplifies this task?

Comment: "the company logo should be placed between the two central slides" which is the company logo?

Comment: I didn't draw it, it's just a fixed picture that stays permanently between the two central slides.

Comment: Just added a star instead of a logo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, had to create a new effect for the Swiper, a duplicate of "creative".
In this effect use the variable "progress", which shows where the slide is at the moment. 0 is the center, 1 is the first element, -1 is minus the first element. If progress < 0, you subtract 0.5, and if it is greater than 0, you add 0.5.Thus an empty space is formed just in the center.